# rails `bundle install` trying to install system wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I accidentally ran `sudo bundle install` and now when I run just `bundle install` I get an error:

> Error details:
>
> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -

here are the environment/bundler settings:

```
Environment
      
  Bundler   1.12.3
  Rubygems  2.6.4
  Ruby      2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin14]
  GEM_HOME  /Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  GEM_PATH  /Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  RVM       1.27.0 (latest)
  Git       2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
  rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
      
      Bundler settings
      
  orig_path
    Set via BUNDLE_ORIG_PATH: "/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/bin"
  orig_gem_path
    Set via BUNDLE_ORIG_GEM_PATH: "/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global"
```

is it trying to install system gems rather than just for my rails app? how can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you to remove all gems with sudo command, `sudo rm -rf /Users/abdulahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the global rubygems with :

`sudo gem update --system --no-user-install.`

Or try this:

```
bundle install --path ~/.gem
```

Other option is just uninstall bundler and install it again.

Comment: I actually tried this before asking but it didn't work :/

Comment: did you try what above comment has suggested?

Comment: I uninstalled bundler and reinstalled and it worked. add that to your answer and I will accept